# making android emulator work for 1600x1200

Tags: android, emulation

I've tried editing android's skin layout in the emulator to be 1600x1200 and the emulator fails to bring up a window. It works fine for smaller resolutions like 1024x480 and such but not big resolutions. Although even with 1024x480, part of the emulator window is inaccessible and not visible. My question is whether anyone has made this work and if so what does their layout file or other changes look like?

Answer (score 2):

The emulator currently doesn't support this (it is a limit on the size of some memory areas it uses).  You don't need to run with such a resolution, though, because there are no devices shipping with that size.

For sizes like 1024x480 that you say parts are not visible, I assume this is because the window at the resolution doesn't fit on your computer's screen?  If so, you can supply an argument to the emulator (I forget what it is exactly) to scale the screen down so it will fit.  Though of course you won't then be seeing all of the pixels your app is drawing.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is helpful. I tried providing the emulator with 1248 MB (Seems to be the max it can support is 2047) and it still failed. I would have thought 2047MB would be sufficient to handle a 1600x1200 display. The exact command I used is: emulator -avd bigscreen -debug all -scale 0.5 -verbose -memory 1248 -data /home/jacob/.android/avd/bigscreen.avd/userdata.img -system /home/jacob/original_android_tree/out/target/product/generic/system.img -sdcard /home/jacob/.android/avd/bigscreen.avd/sdcard.img . I am making my own device. If it can't be done, I'd like to try to solve it.

Comment: You will need to build a new emulator binary that can handle it.  I don't recall exactly where the limit comes from to help any more than that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible to change the resolution of the emulator to 1600x1200, but why do you want to do that?

Android doesn't support that resolutions. With gingerbread, maximum resolution will be 1280×760.

Comment: Where do you see that Android doesn't support that resolution? Its fine if you don't know how to do it, but don't tell people its not possible unless you know that for sure.

Comment: Please, take a look at your reading comprehension. I said "Android doesn't support..." rather than "Emulator doesn't support"... I ask again: Why do you want to do that?