# Android: Emulator fails to start with FullHD resolution being set

Tags: android, android-emulator

I need to test an android application on FullHD resolution screen (1920x1080). I've tried different Android SDK versions: 2.1, 2.2, 3.0 with no luck. Every time I try to start an emulator with the resolution being set, it just hangs and shows a black screen permanently. Does anyone have an idea how to test an application on 1920x1080?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the setting of resolution 1920x1080. The DDMS show that the underlying bootstrap module tries to start the system again and again. However, every time the system tries to initialize something related to graphics hardware, is crashes.

```
04-19 10:06:42.235: INFO/SurfaceFlinger(241): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
```

Which comes along with a mass of memory leak messages.

```
04-19 10:06:42.386: INFO/DEBUG(30): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
04-19 10:06:42.386: INFO/DEBUG(30): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic:2.3.3/GRI34/101070:eng/test-keys'
04-19 10:06:42.386: INFO/DEBUG(30): pid: 241, tid: 249  >>> system_server <<<
04-19 10:06:42.386: INFO/DEBUG(30): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0000005c
04-19 10:06:42.386: INFO/DEBUG(30):  r0 00158220  r1 4373bdc4  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
04-19 10:06:42.386: INFO/DEBUG(30):  r4 001581d8  r5 001dc7e0  r6 00000000  r7 00000000
04-19 10:06:42.386: INFO/DEBUG(30):  r8 a811cb25  r9 0007e0a8  10 00100000  fp 00000001
04-19 10:06:42.386: INFO/DEBUG(30):  ip ac52c794  sp 4373bd58  lr af9049c0  pc ac518fd2  cpsr 40000030
04-19 10:06:42.526: INFO/DEBUG(30):          #00  pc 00018fd2  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so
04-19 10:06:42.526: INFO/DEBUG(30):          #01  pc 000194f8  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so
04-19 10:06:42.526: INFO/DEBUG(30):          #02  pc 00024a34  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so
04-19 10:06:42.526: INFO/DEBUG(30):          #03  pc 0001c668  /system/lib/libutils.so
04-19 10:06:42.536: INFO/DEBUG(30):          #04  pc 0001cbb6  /system/lib/libutils.so
04-19 10:06:42.536: INFO/DEBUG(30):          #05  pc 00011a7c  /system/lib/libc.so
04-19 10:06:42.536: INFO/DEBUG(30):          #06  pc 00011640  /system/lib/libc.so
04-19 10:06:42.536: INFO/DEBUG(30): code around pc:
04-19 10:06:42.536: INFO/DEBUG(30): ac518fb0 e81cf7fe 1c311c20 f7ff3048 6ca5ffb9 
04-19 10:06:42.536: INFO/DEBUG(30): ac518fc0 6eef2300 6aea9706 6b2961e2 9e066221
```

As a result, **such a setting causes memory leak**, just try other resolutions.

For more discussion, refer to [making android emulator work for 1600x1200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948775/making-android-emulator-work-for-1600x1200).

Comment: But I really need to test my app on the resolution, so just switching to a lower one won't work.

Comment: Maybe to get a device supporting fullhd? The problem is an emulator limitation.

Comment: is the limitation specified anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Use AndroVM http://androvm.org/blog/

It's a lot faster because of android-x86 and even supports many resolution above 1920X1080