# Emulating a FULL HD(1920×1080) android device. Max resolution honeycomb runs on?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Can the current android release run on a full hd device/ emulator. I tried setting the emulator resolution to 1920x1080 but it doesn't work. The emulator window opens but android doesn't begin booting. Actually nothing higher than HD ready(1280 × 720) works.

I have read this old thread [making-android-emulator-work-for-1600x1200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948775/making-android-emulator-work-for-1600x1200) that "gingerbread, maximum resolution will be 1280×760". I haven't found anything like this on the android site, plus there been Honeycomb release in the mean time. Is it true that we can't test android apps for 1920x1080 screens?

If it's possible how can it be done. I've also tried android x86 in a virtual box and it has the same resolution limitation. While the Google TV add-on supports FULL HD resolution it doesn't support NDK which I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714576/android-emulator-fails-to-start-with-fullhd-resolution-being-set) SO post, the emulator can't handle this resolution. I've tried this with my up-to-date emulator&sdk, the problem still exists.

With Android-x86 and Virtualbox it is possible to raise the resolution. When I've set the uvesa_mode to 1920x1080, but the started VM ran only on 1580x1080.

Answer (score 1):

Use AndroVM http://androvm.org/blog/

It's much faster and even supports many resolution above 1920X1080

Answer (score 0):

[Nox Emulator](https://www.bignox.com/) now supports 1920x1080 resolution. You'll have better experience if you enable virtualization in BIOS.